# Trouble doing backup with tar using the results of find command

Tags: linux, bash, backup, tar, perl

So I'm doing this perl script to backup my music. It will search for new music added to my disk since the last backup.

When this command runs:

```
find ~/Music -type f -mtime -145 | xargs tar -cvf backup.tar
```

I get output like this:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/amonteiro/Music/UFOmammut/8: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: (2017)/08: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: PSYRCLE.ogg: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /home/amonteiro/Music/UFOmammut/8: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: (2017)/01: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: BABEL.ogg: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /home/amonteiro/Music/UFOmammut/8: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: (2017)/03: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: ZODIAC.ogg: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /home/amonteiro/Music/UFOmammut/8: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: (2017)/02: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: WARSHEEP.ogg: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /home/amonteiro/Music/UFOmammut/8: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: (2017)/06: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: CORE.ogg: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /home/amonteiro/Music/UFOmammut/8: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: (2017)/04: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

I've tried everything that I had found but not having luck.

Any opinions? Please.

Comment: "I've tried everything that I had found but not having luck.", what have you tried?

Comment: Some variations of the find and tar command. I tried saving the find results in a file ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spaces in filenames, so use the `null char` :

```
find ~/Music -type f -mtime -145 -print0 | xargs -0 tar --null -cvf backup.tar
```

Comment: What about if I don't want to create a tar file. Instead I would like to add to an existing tar file.
find ~/Music -type f -mtime -145 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rvf backup.tar - the output:
xargs: WARNING: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed through in the argument list.  Did you mean to use the --null option?
tar: Options '-[0-7][lmh]' not supported by *this* tar
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: I added the script in the description so you can check.

Comment: Yes, use `tar --null`